# how to get type of relationship in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For example:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

I wanna somehow get the type of `children` which should be `one2many` and the type of `parent` which should be `many2one`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct way:

```
Parent.children.prop.direction.name
```